# Convert .xml configuration to spring boot application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am transferring my spring mvc project to spring boot and i am trying to convert the old school .xml configuration to application properties.I have only figured out the jdbc and jsp properties. Any ideas?

.xml config

```
<bean id="trans"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="trans" />

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=asdf
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

found this as an alternative but would if someone know the setting for application.properties

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConf {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

Comment: It is enough for initial Spring boot configuration.. You can also configure Spring boot using .yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Beans cannot be defined in application.properties I suppose. Has to be in a class with @configuration annotation, bean with @bean.